# ¿Por qué no puedo redefinir una lista en el intérprete como resultado de una función sobre ella misma?

Tags: haskell, lista

Confieso que me estoy enamorando de Haskell, estoy dándole duro a las listas y las funciones que se le pueden aplicar:

```
Prelude> let list = [1,2,3,4,5]
Prelude> head list
1
Prelude> tail list
[2,3,4,5]
Prelude> init list
[1,2,3,4]
Prelude> last list
5
Prelude> take 2 list
[1,2]
Prelude> drop 3 list
[4,5]
Prelude> reverse list 
[5,4,3,2,1]
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Maravilla, entiendo que las funciones que me devuelven una lista (como `tail`, `init`, `reverse`, etc.) no afectan la lista usada como parámetro, es decir, la lista original `list` no ha sido modificada y se retorna una copia (?) de esa lista:

```
Prelude> list
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Lo que traté de hacer es algo muy sencillo:

```
Prelude> let list = reverse list
```

En mi cabeza esperaba que ahora `list` contenga `[5,4,3,2,1]`, pero al tratar de ver lo que contiene simplemente se cuelga el intérprete:

```
Prelude> list
(el cursor se queda acá y no hace nada)
```

¿Por qué está pasando esto?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Haskell es un lenguaje **funcional puro**, por lo que no existen los efectos secundarios y *no hay estado*: toda función tiene un resultado, y *siempre el mismo resultado* si sus parámetros son idénticos.

A esto hemos de sumarle que en Haskell todas las variables son, en cierto modo, funciones:  Un valor constante como el que has definido puede entenderse como una función sin argumentos.

De esta forma, tu código:

```
let list = reverse list
```

podría traducirse a un lenguaje imperativo como:

```
fun list () {
    return reverse(list())
}
```

Con esta hipotética traducción deberías entender mejor lo que está ocurriendo:  Al intentar evaluar `list`, esto se traduce en tratar de evaluar `reverse list`.  Esto es claramente recursivo, y sin un caso base que lo pare, el resultado es un bucle infinito.

Comment: Creo que mi problema es que siempre trato de pasar lo que hago en Haskell a Python, debería hacer algún tipo de meditación antes de practicar mi Haskell-fu para vaciar mi mente, gran explicación, me quedó clarísimo.

Comment: "Computer Science Courses that Don't Exist, But Should - CSCI 2100: Unlearning Object-Oriented Programming" :) http://prog21.dadgum.com/210.html

Comment: @astrojuanlu jajajaja,  ¡excelente!

Comment: @astrojuanlu el problema no es aprender un paradigma, sino creer que todo debe encajar con ese paradigma y que se vuelva tu dogma y un estigma...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza cierto, cuando te acostumbras a un paradigma te da paradigmatitis

Comment: @CésarBustíos Para Haskell conviene recordar siempre que *todo son funciones*. No hay variables, solo funciones de aridad 0. Evaluar un valor es llamar a una función, y el símbolo `=` no es *asignación* sino *definición*.  Es prácticamente como definir fórmulas matemáticas, en realidad...

Comment: @Darkhogg gracias, lo tendré en cuenta.

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta de Darkhogg, aunque sí señala que la causa es una definición recursiva, no me parece precisa.  Primero que nada, la pureza funcional y falta de estado no son la causa de este problema.  Aunque sí es cierto que no podemos modificar los **valores** en Haskell, sí podemos **opacar los nombres** localmente con definiciones de alcanze más corto ("shadow a binding with another one in a narrower scope").  Esto es fácil de demostrar en el intérprete:

```
GHCi, version 7.10.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> let lista = [1..5]
Prelude> let ejemplo xs = xs ++ lista
Prelude> lista
[1,2,3,4,5]
Prelude> ejemplo [4]
[4,1,2,3,4,5]
Prelude> let lista = [1..3]
Prelude> lista
[1,2,3]
Prelude> ejemplo [4]
[4,1,2,3,4,5]
```

Se ve que:

1. Pudimos redefinir el nombre `lista`.
2. Cada uso del nombre se refiere al valor que está en alcanze ("in scope") en ese uso.  Por ejemplo:

   - La función `ejemplo` se definió en un contexto en que `lista = [1..5]`.
   - Por lo tanto, el valor de `ejemplo [4]` no cambia después de la redefinición de `lista`—`ejemplo` continua siendo la misma función que era en su punto de definición.

La redefinición no modificó el valor antiguo de `lista`, su único efecto es en las definiciones posteriores.  Las definiciones anteriores mantienen el mismo sentido original.  O más precisamente:

1. El alcanze ("scope") de cada definición son las expresiones siguientes.
2. Definiciones tardías del mismo nombre **opacan** ("shadow") las definiciones más tempranas.
3. Cada uso de un nombre se refiere a la definición anterior más próxima.

Lo segundo que cabe notar es que no es buena idea pensar que en Haskell "todas las variables son, en cierto modo, funciones."  Pensar de ese modo lo que hace es confundir el asunto.  En Haskell todas las funciones son valores, pero no todos los valores son funciones.

Para entender la dificultad del ejemplo lo que hay que notar es que Haskell, a diferencia de casi cualquier otro lenguaje común, permite definiciones recursivas no solo de de funciones sino también de valores.  Por ejemplo, la siguiente función construye una lista circular:

```
cycle :: [a] -> [a]
cycle as = let result = as ++ result in result
```

En esta definición, la variable `result` se usa simultáneamente en el lado izquierdo como el derecho de su definición, tanto como el nombre que definimos, y como argumento a la función que produce el valor que le asignamos al nombre.  En Haskell esto funciona, gracias a la "vagancia" ("lazy evaluation").  Lo podemos ilustrar mediante un argumento ecuacional:

```
-- Definición de `++`
(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
[] ++ ys = ys
(x:xs) ++ ys = x : (xs ++ ys)

-- Definición de `take`
take :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
take _ [] = []
take n (a:as)
  | n <= 0 = []
  | otherwise = a : take (n - 1) as

-- Demostración
take 3 (cycle [1, 2])
  = take 3 (let result = [1, 2] ++ result in result)
  = take 3 (let result = [1, 2] ++ result in [1, 2] ++ result)
  = take 3 (let result = [1, 2] ++ result in 1 : ([2] ++ result))
  = 1 : take 2 (let result = [1, 2] ++ result in [2] ++ result)
  = 1 : take 2 (let result = [1, 2] ++ result in 2 : ([] ++ result))
  = 1 : 2 : take 1 (let result = [1, 2] ++ result in [] ++ result)
  = 1 : 2 : take 1 (let result = [1, 2] ++ result in result)
  = 1 : 2 : take 1 (let result = [1, 2] ++ result in [1, 2] ++ result)
  = 1 : 2 : take 1 (let result = [1, 2] ++ result in 1 : ([2] ++ result))
  = 1 : 2 : 1 : take 0 (let result = [1, 2] ++ result in [2] ++ result)
  = 1 : 2 : 1 : []
  = [1, 2, 1]
```

Aunque este concepto parezca algo exótico, resulta ser muy útil, porque significa que podemos construir, sin esfuerzo alguno, gráficas de objetos inmutables con referencia mutua.

Y ahora podemos reexaminar tu ejemplo:

```
Prelude> let list = reverse list
```

Tu expectativa es que en el lado derecho del `=`, el nombre `list` se refiere a su definición anterior, en otro alcanze ("scope").  En casi cualquier otro idioma esa expectativa sería correcta, pero no lo es en Haskell—en esta definición, `list` en la derecha se refiere a `list` en la izquierda.

Comment: Por mucho que te empeñes esto te va a seguir sin dejar definir `lista` en función de *la anterior definición del nombre `lista`*. La pregunta no trataba simplemente sobre redefinir, sino sobre *usar un valor previo*.  El ejemplo que pones al final es lo que se llama *memoización*, y se basa precisamente en la pureza funcional del lenguaje. No estás reutilizando un valor previo, sino el actual mediante una definición recursiva.

Comment: @Darkhogg: la memoización es una cosa relacionada pero estrictamente aparte de la pureza funcional. Por ejemplo en Scheme—que no es un idioma puro—existen constructos de memoización desde hace ya décadas (la forma especial `delay` y la función `force`). Y en Haskell la memoización no es un requisito del lenguaje sino una estrategia de implementación—de esto se trata la sutil distinción entre ["non-strict semantics" vs. "lazy evaluation"](https://wiki.haskell.org/Lazy_vs._non-strict). La demostración que di de `take 3 (cycle [1, 2])` es ecuacional y no usa memoización, por ejemplo.